# How to conditionally load a JavaScript script in `functions.php` for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Been trying to enqueue script for the archive page, to no avail.

I've checked the source code for HTML (Ctrl + U), but the script doesn't load.
I've tried using is_post_type_archive(), still no.
I've put the `enqueue_script` in a different function as well.

```
function theme_resources() { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'infiniteSlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/infiniteSlider.js', array( 'ui' ), '1.0.0', true );

        if (is_archive()) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'infiniteScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/infiniteScroll.js', array( ... ) );
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_resources');
```

Comment: does the script load without the conditional?

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'infiniteSlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/infiniteSlider.js', array( 'ui' ), '1.0.0', true );
```

i would venture to say that 'ui' script does not exist. since this is a dependency, the whole script is not being loaded. probably you mean 'jquery' instead?

is_archive() is correct. but you had array(...) in your code, which actually throws an error. this should work:

```
   if (is_archive()) {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'infiniteSlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/infiniteSlider.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, but it does when I remove the `if (is_archive()) {...}` lines.

Comment: interesting. i actually tested it on a project to make sure and the script is as expected on the archive pages but not on all others. so, this must work. debug it and see where it goes wrong (debug by using var_dump() or echo. 
MAYBE it's naming problem. use another name than infiniteSlider, just to test.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a custom post type, just the default page for displaying blog posts, so instead of `is_archive()`, I should use `is_home()`, like so:
`if ( is_home() ) {...}`